# Can't change login pw

Tags: login-screen, password-recovery

Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS. Have forgotten my login PW so have attempted to change it following these directions
https://itsfoss.com/how-to-hack-ubuntu-password/

> Boot into recovery mode
>   Get into shell prompt
>   $ mount -rw -o remount /
>   $ passwd jim
>   $ new password
>   $ new password
>   $ exit

Then booted normally. 
However it didn't work. My new pw that is.

Am I at least correct in assuming my username is correct?

What should I try next?
Any feedback welcome!

[image]

Comment: Were you using encryption?   You won't be able to login with a GUI if your $HOME directory has no space available (needed to create temporary work files; certain encrypted home setups with a changed password will mean encryption isn't unlocked thus no space available), so I test via login with text terminal (to confirm password works, also I can check/look around there for issues that may cause GUI logins to fail; or  in-out loops

Comment: Thanks! So no space available a definite possibility. How to login via text terminal?

Comment: I use ctrl+alt+F4 to switch to tty4 (I opt for F4 or F5 as space either side of keys means I don't need to look) and enter my username & password.  Depending on release (and setup) you switch back to GUI with ctrl+alt+F7 (F8 rarely) or on many modern systems ctrl+alt+F1.  `df -hl` will show diskfree (human format & local drives only... only /home impacts GUI login, but if it shares / partition it'll be / you need to look at)

Comment: thanks so freed up space in /home but still showing 100% usage in /
What is the safest way to make space in root from the text terminal?

Comment: It'll depend on how much space was allocated (recommended minimum was 25GB for Ubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE says 16GB (https://ubuntu-mate.org/about/requirements/), so did you start with that? more? or less). What software did you add? (the more you add the more space you needed to allocate; also what format/how installed, as some need more space than others). What software did you use, is space lost in logs? containerized setup,  or detail that requires exploration rather than a blank suggestion...